# Problems with lag function(db2)

Tags: db2

I have a table that contains the following columns:

```
userid  Designation load_dt     audit_time  type  
A       Engg        3/11/2015   22/06/2015   R        
A       Engg        4/11/2015   03/07/2015   D            
A       Engg        31/12/9999  4/10/2015    R    
A       doc         31/12/9999  22/06/2015   R
```

I am trying to create an output by tracking the change in audit_time on the basis of userid and designation. for first row, start date will be 01-01-1900 and if no other record exists then end date would be 12-31-9999. For userid = A, since the change happened on 03/07/2015, so first record gets start date from 01/01/1900 and got end dated on 03/07/2015. second record gets the start date as 03/07/2015 and remains active till 4/10/2015. The third change started from 04/10/2015 and has future end date.

```
userid  Designation load_dt     audit_time  type  start_date   end_date

A       Engg        3/11/2015   22/06/2015  R     01/01/1900   03/07/2015       
A       Engg        4/11/2015   03/07/2015  D   **03/07/2015   4/10/2015            
A       Engg        31/12/9999  4/10/2015    R  **4/10/2015    31/12/9999   
A       doc         31/12/9999  22/06/2015   R    01/01/1900   31/12/9999
```

I used the following query:

```
select userid, designation, LOAD_DT, AUDIT_TIME, TYPE   
, coalesce(lag(AUDIT_TIME ) over (partition by userid, designation order by AUDIT_TIME),'1900-01-01') start   
, coalesce(lead(AUDIT_TIME ) over (partition by userid, designation order by AUDIT_TIME),'9999-12-31') enddt   
from DUMMY1;
```

I am getting the following results:

```
userid  Designation load_dt     audit_time  type  start_date   end_date   
A       Engg        3/11/2015   22/06/2015   R    01/01/1900   03/07/2015   
A       Engg        4/11/2015   03/07/2015   D  **22/06/2015   4/10/2015        
A       Engg        31/12/9999  4/10/2015    R  **03/07/2015   31/12/9999   
A       doc         31/12/9999  22/06/2015   R    01/01/1900   31/12/9999
```

I hope I am able to explain my problem correctly.

Comment: It's clear you've pasted this from something else, because your statement has syntax errors (you haven't defined the alias `s`, and are using two different names for the audit column).  Otherwise... are you sure these are the results you want?  Usually the first row would represent the insertion, so whatever it is didn't exist before that point - normally you'd either use the "current" value, or add an extra row (for "before we have info")

Comment: I accidently forgot to remove "s", my concern was more related towards data and not regarding the syntax error. My bad, that alias name got copied there.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by just tweaking the lag calculation:

```
select userid, designation, LOAD_DT, AUDIT_TIME, TYPE   
, case when lag(AUDIT_TIME ) over (partition by userid, designation order by AUDIT_TIME) then '1900-01-01' else audit_time end start   
, coalesce(lead(AUDIT_TIME) over (partition by userid, designation order by AUDIT_TIME),'9999-12-31') enddt   
from DUMMY1;
```

Comment: This works, but for crufty reasons.  Oh, there's a way to supply a "default" value: `LEAD(audit_time, 1, DATE('9999-12-31'))` (the `1` is the offset).

Comment: Thanks Clockwork-Muse, I didn;t know that we could give a default value as well with lag. I was confused as to how to put the end date of previous record as a start date of its next row. But I was able to figure it out the next morning :). Thats why pasted the results.
Thank you so much for taking out time and replying to my query. :)